# Inserting Increment Values into Table

Tags: t-sql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert values into a table. A few of the fields have declared formulas. The data is increasing properly after the insert.
For example, the field 'SAPPRDONo' should be increasing by 1 for each row, starting with 13366.
Here is my script:

```
      Declare @count int = 1
      Declare @Qty int
      Declare @scrap int
      Declare @lot nvarchar(100)
      Declare @lotno nvarchar(10)
      Declare @insertlot nvarchar(100)
      Declare @yield int = 1
      Declare @prdo int = 1

      While @count <= 100
          Begin
              Set @Qty = round(430 * (@yield/100),0,0)
              Set @insertlot = @lot + @lotno
              Set @scrap = 430 - @qty
          Insert into Report_comp_EWS (SpinwebABI, SAPPRDONo, 
    CompletionType, Quantity, ParentLotNo, NewLotNo, WhseFinish, 
    ItemCodeStart, ItemCodeFinish, ScrapQty) 
    values ('Stress Test', '13366', 'Complete', 4, 'StressTestAuto', 
    'StressTest1', 'E_CHD', 'WA00N44A', 'Lynx', 426)
                Set @count = @count + 1
                Set @yield = @yield + 1
                Set @prdo = 13366 +1
                Set @lotno = @lotno + 1
            End
```

When I insert these values, the field SAPPRDONo is starting with 13366 but is not increasing. For the first row the value should equal '13366', the next row should be '13367', the next is '13367' and so on.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tested setting the declare prdo int = 13366 and then setting the @prdo = 13366 +1

I expect the output of 13366, 13367, 13368 but every single row is returning 13366

Comment: Your insert value for `SAPPRDONo` is always 13366, so this is no surprise. You should set `@prdo` initially to 13366, insert `@prdo` as the value for `SAPPRDONo` in your `insert`, then set `@prdo = @prdo + 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting '13366' for all your rows in the insert query.
You have to increment it.
Try below:

```
  Declare @count int = 1
  Declare @Qty int
  Declare @scrap int
  Declare @lot nvarchar(100)
  Declare @lotno nvarchar(10)
  Declare @insertlot nvarchar(100)
  Declare @yield int = 1
  Declare @prdo int = 13366

  While @count <= 100
      Begin
          Set @Qty = round(430 * @yield)/100,0,0)
          Set @insertlot = @lot + @lotno
          Set @scrap = 430 - @qty
      Insert into Report_comp_EWS (SpinwebABI, SAPPRDONo, 
CompletionType, Quantity, ParentLotNo, NewLotNo, WhseFinish, 
ItemCodeStart, ItemCodeFinish, ScrapQty) 
values ('Stress Test', CAST(@prdo as varchar(5)), 'Complete', 4, 'StressTestAuto', 
'StressTest1', 'E_CHD', 'WA00N44A', 'Lynx', 426)
            Set @count = @count + 1
            Set @yield = @yield + 1
            Set @prdo = @prdo +1 -- increment by 1
            Set @lotno = @lotno + 1
        End
```

UPDATED FORMULA - Qty is returning 0

```
     Declare @count int = 1
        Declare @Qty int 
        Declare @scrap int
        Declare @lot nvarchar(100) = 'StressTest'
        Declare @lotno nvarchar(10) = 1
        Declare @insertlot nvarchar(100)
        Declare @yield int = 1
        Declare @prdo int = 13366

        While @count <= 100
            Begin
        Set @Qty = round(430 * @yield)/100,0,0)
        Set @insertlot = @lot + @lotno
        Set @scrap = 430 - @qty
    Insert into Report_comp_EWS (SpinwebABI, SAPPRDONo, CompletionType, 
    Quantity, ParentLotNo, NewLotNo, WhseFinish, ItemCodeStart, ItemCodeFinish, 
    ScrapQty) values ('Stress Test' , CAST(@prdo as varchar(5)), 'Complete', CAST(@qty as 
    varchar(5)), 'StressTestAuto', Cast(@insertlot as nvarchar(100)), 'E_CHD', 
    'WA00N44A', 'Lynx', 426)
                Set @count = @count + 1
                Set @yield = @yield + 1
                Set @prdo = @prdo +1
                Set @lotno = @lotno + 1
                       End
```

Comment: Thank you. I will. I am having an issue with the Qty variable as well. I need it to be multiplied by the yield then divided by 100. The yield begins with 1 and then increases to 2, 3, 4, etc. For example, for the first row it should be 430 * 1(yield)/100, which would be equal to 4.3, rounds up to 4. The second row should be 430 * 2/100, which would be 9. For the second row it is currently returning 4. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the value you are getting for first row?

Comment: I am getting 0 with the following formula.

Comment: Replace your formula with -- Set @Qty = round((430 * @yield)/100,0,0) . You need to multiple first and then divide.